# Is there a Puranic basis for Graha relationships in Jyotisha? Else what is their basis as is traditionally taught?

Tags: puranas, astrology, tradition, navagraha, explanation

Below is a tabulated form of the friends, the neutrals and the enemies of each graha as per Jyotisha. ([Source](https://hindi.astropankajseth.co.in/2016/01/15/%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9-%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%80-%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8-%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%B2/)):

| Graha | Friend | Neutral | Enemy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Surya** | Chandra, Mangala, Guru | Budha | Shukra, Shani |
| **Chandra** | Surya, Guru | Mangala, Budha, Shukra, Shani | - |
| **Mangala** | Surya, Chandra, Guru | Shukra, Shani | Budha |
| **Budha** | Surya, Shukra | Mangala, Guru, Shani | Chandra |
| **Guru** | Surya, Chandra, Mangala | Shani | Budha, Shukra |
| **Shukra** | Budha, Shani | Mangala, Guru | Surya, Chandra |
| **Shani** | Budha, Shukra | Guru | Surya, Chandra, Mangala |

Interestingly if one observes, some of these relationships have a Puranic backing. For example,

1. Due to the Tarakama Yuddha, Budha hates Chandra for his misdemeanour, Guru being Guru of even Chandra, is friendly with him but is inimical towards the product of Chandra’s misdemeanour i.e. Budha.
2. Surya hates Shani for supposedly eclipsing him when he was born.
3. Guru hates Shukra being Daitya Guru. Wonder why Shukra doesn’t reciprocate?
4. Surya Chandra Mangala Guru are mutual friends (except one case of neutrality), which can be attributed to Guru being these Deva planets’ Guru.

**Question:**
Are there any such Puranic legends which can serve in providing the reason for the friendly, neutral and inimical relationships between Grahas. If yes, please mention very briefly (1-2 lines per relation) with citation.

If besides those mentioned, there are none, then please provide some basis or logic for their relationships like their nature of Deva, Daitya, etc.; Varna; ruling tattvas, etc. or another logic/ way for easy remembrance as is traditionally taught. It’s very difficult to remember otherwise.

---

<sup>Note: Mentioning incidents and citation from Purāṇa is sufficient eg. tarakama Yuddha, Matsya Purāṇa Chapter XYZ, else answer will become very long. If no story then basic explanation with 2-3 examples for the traditional way/logic/basis for remembering will suffice. Also do correct if something above has been written down wrongly. **Information about Rahu Ketu is more than welcome**.</sup>

Comment: Philosophically Vayu, Prithvi elements are one category and Agni, Jala are other category. Shani and Sun are mutual enemies. Moon is only Jala and has no enemies. Guru represents Akasa and no one considers him enemy. Prithvi is slightly different to Vayu. If you understand what exactly are Panchabhutas and how they are everywhere, you can understand easily these relationships.

Comment: @TheDestroyer thanks :) What about Shukra who’s Jala?

Comment: Every planet has more than one element but one element is predominating. BHPS 3.28 say "सुखी कान्तवपुः श्रेष्ठः सुलोचनो भृगोः सुतः। काव्यकर्ता कफाधिक्योऽनिलात्मा वक्रमृधैजः॥२८ ॥ Description of Sukra. Sukra is charming, has a splendorous physique, is excellent, or great in disposition, has charming eyes, is a poet, is kapha (phlegmatic) and Anila (windy) and has curly hair". He also has Air element since it is "seed of desire". It owns One Air (which is Mulatrikona) and one earthy sign. So, it is friend of Saturn and Saturn also like venus in return due to Air element.

Answer (score 0):

> please provide some basis or logic for their relationships

There's definitely a secondary and hidden meaning into the relationships, that is not possible to give to laymen outside the Sampradaaya.

As for the basic, easily available reasoning, it's in Brihat Paraashara Hora Shastra:

[image: -]
[Source](https://archive.org/details/BPHSEnglish/BPHS%20-%201%20RSanthanam/page/n37/mode/1up?view=theater)

You can do the calculations yourself based on ownerships of Raashis by Grahas as well as MulaTrikona of Grahas. Or maybe another person can edit my answer and do that.

I'm posting the relevant table here since I had it lying around, although it's not in English.

[image: table]

The Grahas in *Italics*, the Raashis are owned by themselves. As for Shukra's enemies, Brhaspati is taken out of it since Shukra is exalted in Pisces (owned by Brhaspati) and he is put as neutral (which is not shown in this table). The same is the case for Mangala with regards to Shani.

Comment: Btw Dushyant idk if you or Bingming said this, but Graha represented the planet and Deva represented the deity presiding it correct?

Comment: Yes, that sort of classification is usually used in Nakshatras. For eg: Krittika Nakshatra Graha Aadhipati (VImshottari) is Surya and the Devataa is Agni.

Not sure I'm the one who has said this though. Perhaps BingMing, who you're referring to. @Haridasa

Comment: Okay, I tried telling my mother that in theory as per Shastra the man is the head of the family they just shut me down (as expected) without even letting me finish. Liberal mindsets are of that nature though. I will have to live isolated by myself after my child years and simply give them money to provide them. They're great parents after all, but not good Shastra followers.

Comment: I think it's relevant that you should be aware of 1.30-31 of Paraashara Dharma Shastra. "In the Kali, Adharma is overpowered Dharma, lies have overpowered truth, thieves have overpowered kings and *women have overpowered men*"30 - "... This is always what happens in the Kali"31.

It's really not something that you need to interfere in, the Yugas are controlled by higher powers, you just need to do your own Karma and Saadhana and gain higher knowledge. Trying to convince others is also not a positive trait. Also, this is off topic for this question. You should contact elsewhere. @Haridasa

Comment: Okay, but another issue of mine is I cannot fully understand the old ways for today's times.

Comment: Certain views seem glorious others seem regressive and no longer logical and only being clinged to due to faith and not reason.

Comment: Is it alright if we chat it's like two sides of my mind are conflicting one liberal, one conservative, and one purely rational, and the latter (last one) is siding with some of the old and some of the new based on the changing landscape.

Comment: It's like I have the mindset, but not enough knowledge or guidance even though I have tons of guidance if you understand what I mean. This causes a sense of distress. But, I also feel something is missing something which will help me further my understanding to me the Dharmashastras must be defended and they very well can be.